# Execute custom script on refactor operation when using Visual Studio Database project

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, database-project

If I refactor a database column using the Schema View in Visual Studio I will get a refactor log like this:

```
 <Operation Name="Rename Refactor" Key="32f8afe4-af53-441d-a93b-46097d19b4ae" ChangeDateTime="02/24/2014 08:53:02">
    <Property Name="ElementName" Value="[dbo].[table1].[col1]" />
    <Property Name="ElementType" Value="ISqlSimpleColumn" />
    <Property Name="ParentElementName" Value="[dbo].[table1]" />
    <Property Name="ParentElementType" Value="ISql90Table" />
    <Property Name="NewName" Value="[col1Refactored]" />
  </Operation>
```

Lets say I want to run some custom scripts only if this certain refactor is triggered when deploying. How can I do this?

Comment: One _possible_ solution (untested) would be to tweak the __RefactorLog table to include an "inserted date" column with a default of GETDATE(). If that GUID was fired this time around, run your script. Other possibility would be to track through DDL triggers if you don't disable them during deployment.  If this is something that depends on that new name, you probably need to handle this in a special case because it could fail to build/publish properly if that column isn't present.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I was hoping for a "built in" solution but I guess I will have to settle with a workaround.